# Value annotation can't find a value if it's a number

Tags: java, spring, spring-4

Application.yaml:

```
request.delay.ms: 200
```

A spring component:

```
@Value("${request.delay.ms}")
private long requestDelay;
```

Now, as strange as it sounds, it looks like spring can successfully resolve the property if it's value is a string, i.e. if I change `200` to `200a`. It does throw an error 
`Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "200a"` but that's expected.

If I change the value back to `200` I get 
`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${request.delay.ms}"`

And if I run tomcat in debug mode and step through the spring code, it works fine with no errors.

String @Value(s) are resolved fine in the same component all the time.

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: Total guess: `request.delay.ms: "200"`?

Comment: This works fine for me.

Comment: I would guess it'd be a particular spring version. Although even bumping up spring boot to the latest 1.2.7 didn't help. I'll try to come up with a small project

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `YAML` instead of `.properties` you should write it in the following manner:

```
request:
  delay:
    ms: 200
```

which will be transformed to properties:

`request.delay.ms=200` but you are mixing both files

See more [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml)

Comment: How does this explain the case op `200a`?

Comment: First of all there are a lot of there are a lot of errors in this piece of code. The main problem is that `${request.delay.ms}` is never resolved to real value but is always resolved to value `"${request.delay.ms}"` as `String`  and exceptions are raised because `"${request.delay.ms}"` cannot be converted to `long` and if he changes `requestDelay` to `String` no exception is raised because `"${request.delay.ms}"` can be converted to `String` and the value of `requestDelay` will be `"${request.delay.ms}"`

Comment: that doesn't help. Neither replacing it with `request_delay_ms`

Comment: i tested it on my own and worked fine...can you please provide us small spring or spring boot project...